# Replacing functions in the std namespace

Tags: c++, std

I have a library that replaces `free`, `malloc` and a couple of other functions by using a define in it's header:

```
#define free some_custom_free
```

This unfortunately horribly breaks when other libraries (boost in this case) use `std::free` instead of directly calling `free`:

```
error: 'some_custom_free' is not a member of 'std'
```

Can this be properly and portably solved, preferably without having to touch either libraries?

Comment: You could stop using that library?

Comment: Why are you rewriting the C standard library? Or well, the library writer.

Comment: Delete the library from your system.

Comment: it was not allowed to modify/add functions in namespace std

Comment: This is like running with nuclear-powered scissors.

Comment: @aschepler: Hah. I didn't write the lib, I'm as baffled as you are :)

Comment: Howabout #undef before you include boost, and #define it again afterwards? (If you really need these functions to be globally remapped, otherwise just undefine it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You're screwed a thousand ways from Sunday because the library that used `#define` was written by an Australopithecus. The only solution is to change the library that did `#define free`.

Comment: What -should- be the approach for libraries that wish to replace the way the system allocates/frees memory? tmalloc and jemalloc just to name examples :)

Comment: @DanielSloof: The Standard does not provide any reasonable means of replacing the implementation of `malloc` and `free`. Ask your system vendor if they provide a useful mechanism. Or just ask the authors of jemalloc/tmalloc.

Comment: A way to replace them, would be to simply link against another malloc/free/ect, than the one in the clib.

Answer (score 1):

You SHOULD use `__malloc_hook`, which allows you to change what `malloc` does.

- set `__malloc_hook` to actaully run `some_custom_malloc`
- set `__free_hook` to run `some_custom_free`
- remove the `#define` and everything will work fine!

Another option - make sure the `#include` for this library are always AFTER the `#include` for boost / stl / whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... in another words, it's an issue with the malloc library. I'll discuss it upstream.

Comment: What do you mean "it's an issue with the malloc library"? It's an issue with someone doing `#define free ...`, which I'm guessing isn't in the malloc library...

Comment: By 'malloc' library I meant the library that provides the #define. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, right. Definitively an issue with that library. But you can still probably fix this with reordering of the `#include` directives so this library is always last